# How can i change a value in an generic arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

It's a code about a 'shopping cart' that can hold items of a class called 'item'. I had to complete the class 'item' and write another class 'discount' that can reduces the price of an item.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shoppingcart extends Item {

  // all shopping carts:
  private ArrayList<Shoppingcart> allshoppingcart = new ArrayList<Shoppingcart>();
  //Items in the shopping cart:
  private ArrayList<Item> content = new ArrayList<Item>();
  // Counter for shopping carts
  private static int number;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */

  public Shoppingcart() {

    allshoppingcart .add(this);
    this.number = number ;
    this.number++;

  }

  /**
   * load something in Shoppingcart
   */
  public void load(Item i) {
    this.content.add(i);
  }

  /**
   * Sum of all items loaded in the shoppingcart
   *
   * @return sum of the content in the shopping cart
   */
  public double sumShoppingCart() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (Item i : content) {
      sum = sum + item.getPrice();
    }
    return sum;
  }

}
```

The class 'item' so I can store two different types in the arraylist.

```
public class Item {

  // normal price of item
  protected double price;
  // Name of product
  protected String name;

  /**
   * setter for price and name
   */
  public void setPB(String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

  }

  /**
   * getter for price
   */
  public double getPrice() {
    return this.price;
  }

  /**
   * getter for the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

The class 'discount' to reduce an item for an example like a sale (special-offer).

```
public class Discount extends Item
{

    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own


    public Discount()
    {
        // initialise instance variables

    }


    public void makeSale(int percent){

        percent =(100-percent)/100;
        price = w.getPrice()*percent;

    }
}
```

A test class

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Item> content = new ArrayList<>();

    Item item = new Item();
    Item item1 = new Item();
    Item item2 = new Item();

    item.setPB("Steak", 100.00);
    item1.setPB("Water", 200.00);
    item2.setPB("Groceries", 300.00);

    content.add(item);
    content.add(item1);
    content.add(item2);

    System.out.println("The item has the value : " + item.getPrice() + " and the name: " + item.getName());
    System.out.println("There are : " + content.size() + " Item(s) in the shopping cart.");


  }
}
```

How do I access an item and reduce it for a sale?
Thank you

Comment: Did the assignment say you had to make ArrayList<Item> as opposed to ArrayList<Discount>. In any case, it feels like it would be better to make item, item1, and item2 new Discount() so that if you .get() them from the liest, you can call their discount method.

Comment: Yes the task was given and I assume the easiest way would be to write a method in the class item called discount but unfortunately we have to write the 3rd class that inherits of the class item. Probably because it's harder and the learning effect would be greater but the struggle is real

Comment: It makes no sense that Shopingcart extends Item since a Shopingcart object holds a collection of Item objects and a Shopingcart is not a type of Item. Also Discount should not extend Item since it is not a type of Item. Discount should be an instance variable in the Item class instead. You are clearly misusing inheritance and should instead look at composition as a design pattern. I believe once you remove the inheritance then your task will be much easier to solve.

Comment: The problem is that the task was given and the class was half written like that.. Like you said it would be much easier without these constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical OOP exercise. You want to access two different types in a single collection. To do so they both need to have the same interface or parent.

If you use an Abstract base class you can use the following example.
First lets make an abstract Item class:

```
abstract class Item {

  protected double price;
  protected String name;

  public Item(double price, String name) {
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return this.price;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  abstract void discount(double amount);
}
```

and two classes that extend from this base class:

```java
class Food extends Item {

  public Food(double price, String name) {
    super(price, name);
  }

  @Override
  void discount(double amount) {
    this.price -= amount;
  }
}

class Bevarage extends Item {

  public Bevarage(double price, String name) {
    super(price, name);
  }

  @Override
  void discount(double amount) {
    this.price -= amount;
  }
}
```

Now lets make a class discount that has a List items that can discount both items.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Discount {

  public void printAllContent(List<Item> items) {
      items.forEach(item -> System.out.printf("name = %s, price = %.00f \n", item.getName(), item.getPrice()));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Discount card = new Discount();

    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Food(3.0, "burgers"), new Food(9.0, "tomato"), new Food(8.0, "fries"),
        new Bevarage(9.0, "cola"), new Bevarage(12.0, "water"), new Food(2.0, "beer")
    );


    card.printAllContent(items);
    for (Item item : items) {
      item.discount(1.0);
    }

    card.printAllContent(items);
    // if you want to do different discounts for different items
    for(Item item: items) {
      if (item instanceof Bevarage) {
        item.discount(2.0);
      } else {
        item.discount(1.0);
      }
    }
    card.printAllContent(items);
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course, sorry totally forgot :) and thanks again

Answer (score -1):

`java.util.List` has these functions `get(index)` and `set(index, object)`, which you could use:

```java
//1. get your item 
int index = 0;
Item item=content.get(index);

//2. create your discount
Discount discount=new Discount(); 
// Fill/process your discount object with the appropriate data

//3. replace the item with the discount in the list
content.set(index,discount);
```

Comment: 2.5? discount.setPB(item.getName(), item.getPrice()); Or perhaps you are assuming there will be a copy constructor allowing for new Discount(item)?

Comment: @JeremyKahan We don't know how the discount object shall be filled, so I left it "blank". I added a comment line to clarify.

Comment: Okay. It sounded to me like the discount object was supposed to be the original object from the cart, but with the added feature that it could be discounted. But it was not totally clear from the question.